# Add CSS to GWT widget

Tags: css, gwt

How add some style only to GWT container, not to all widget that container contains? For example I need to style CaptionPanel's caption (make it bigger and change color). But when I add style to entire CaptionPanel then all widgets inside inherits added  style too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS 101: restrict your style to the `legend` element that's a child of the `CaptionPanel`. E.g.

```
myCaptionPanel.addStyleName("foo");
```

```
.foo > legend { color: red; }
/* use ".foo legend" above, without the ">" if you need to support IE6 */
```